# How to reduce the decodeImage progress time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm trying to merge two images into one image in my flutter application
I used [Image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) library to do so
but when I use the decodeImage function in this way

```
image.decodeImage(images[0].readAsBytesSync());
```

to merg two images with large size
the app freezed for upto 1 minute
any solution to speed it up

Comment: Dont familiar with this library, but seems like it decoding image on ui thread. You need to use Isolate.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is not freezing, you just have to show loading indicator because this process take time.

> show CircularProgressIndicator until this process doesn't finished.